# The use of string argument in an "IF" statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net, if-statement, highcharts

So, I was trying to make 2 javascript methods. The first method is to do the graphMaking AND the other to send the correct parameters to the first method to make the graph according to the sent parameters.The problem is, i need to loop the parameters sent with "arguments[i]" in order to form a string of:

data[i].Names == "A" || data[i].Names == "B"

and here's what i came up with:

```
  var numIndex = [];
  var cityString = "";
                for (var j = 1; j < arguments.length; j++)
                {
                    cityString = cityString + "||" + " data[i].Names==\"" + arguments[j] + "\"";
                    alert(arguments[j]);
                }
                cityString = "data[i].Names==\"" + arguments[0] + "\"";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (cityString)
      {
        numIndex.push(i);
      }
    }
```

what should my  if (cityString) be replaced with in rder for this to work?
Thanks in advance :)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[EDIT] Okay heres the real deal why its C# is because i was doing the code in asp.net which was dumb of me and heres the real code:

```
function makeGraph() {
        var chrt = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var totalLabel = [];
                var totalValue = [];
                var totalLabel2 = [];
                var totalValue2 = [];
                var cityValue = [];
                var cityName = [];
                var numIndex = [];
                var cityString = "";
                for (var j = 1; j < arguments.length; j++)
                {
                    cityString = cityString + "||" + " data[i].Names==\"" + arguments[j] + "\"";
                    alert(arguments[j]);
                }
                cityString = "data[i].Names==\"" + arguments[0] + "\"";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    totalLabel.push(data[i].Names);
                    totalValue.push(data[i].ValuesDouble);
                    totalLabel2.push(data[i].Names2);
                    totalValue2.push(data[i].ValuesDouble2);
                    if (cityString) {
                        numIndex.push(i);
                    }

                }
                for (var k = 0; k < numIndex.length; k++) {
                    cityValue.push(data[numIndex[k]].ValuesDouble);
                    cityName.push(data[numIndex[k]].Names);
                }

                $(function () {
                    Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: 'black'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: cityName,

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            tickInterval: 100000,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            reversed: false,
                            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                stacking: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [

                        {
                            name: 'Joe',
                            data: cityValue,
                            color: 'green'

                        },
                         {
                             name: 'Joe',
                             data: cityValue,
                             color: 'yellow'
                         },
                        {
                            name: 'Jane',
                            data: cityValue,
                            color: 'blue'
                        }]
                    });
                });

            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Seems like you are using `j` as loop variable, then what is `i` in this scenario?

Comment: sorry, the if (cityString)
    {
    numIndex.push(i);
    } is inside an [i] loop

Comment: Which part of that code is in C#? Can you also post function signatures (or in general more complete code)? It also feels like you are building some sort of script in a string - what do you expect that string to do?

Comment: Again `i` is not defined in `data[i].Name`, Could you please fix the syntax errors first and come back?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found my own answer which was to use eval("if-statement") where if-statement is the if condition in the form of string

Comment: That sounds like an *awful* solution, especially using `eval`.

Comment: Well, I'm really interested if you have a better solution than mine... Please post it. Thanks in advance